# Refer to only lower index in System Verilog

Tags: system-verilog, verification, system-verilog-assertions

I have a bit array A[32][16].

I want to check if any of the lower index values have a certain pattern.

For eg.

A[1][8:0] may have that pattern A[2][8:0] may also have that pattern.

Any thing from A[31 - 0][8:0] may have that pattern. Is there a way to refer to all the higher index components in a single statement.

something like A[5'bxxxxx][8:0] ?

Comment: what is wrong with a `for` loop?

Comment: @Serge, There are times where it is difficult or not possible use procedural code, like in a constraint. Since the OP tagged this with SVA, I assume they are looking to write a boolean expression. In that case, they would have to embed the `for` loop inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax to select a non-contiguous set of bits from an array, packed or unpacked, in a single selection. If `A` is an unpacked array, you can use one of the array reduction methods to create an expression that might suit your needs.

```
if (A.or()  with (item[8:0] == your_pattern) )  // if any match
if (A.and() with (item[8:0] == your_pattern) )  // if all match
```

If `A` is a packed array, you could use replication concatenation to match all

```
if ( {32{ {8'b?,your_pattern} } } ?== A )
```